# ImportError: cannot import name 'Frame' from partially initialized module 'tkinter'

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm an absolute beginner in Python and I'm just trying to follow the steps in a youtube video tutorial on building a python GUI
https://youtu.be/jE-SpRI3K5g

I just wrote this so far:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, Text
import os

root = tk.Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

But I can't proceed with the tutorial as I keep getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Python\TEST2\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tkinter as tk
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from tkinter import messagebox
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\messagebox.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tkinter.commondialog import Dialog
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\commondialog.py", line 13, in <module>
    from tkinter import Frame
ImportError: cannot import name 'Frame' from partially initialized module 'tkinter' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py)
```

I'm trying to learn python from scratch, so please try to explain as simple as possible.
Thank you so much!!

Comment: What is the name of the .py file you are trying to execute?

Comment: I just tried to name the file as "Test GUI.py"

Comment: Did you modify ``C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py``? ``from tkinter import messagebox`` is [not a line that the module should run](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b121a4a45ff4bab8812a9b26ceffe5ad642f5d5a/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I fixed everything by completely uninstalling everything and installing everything related to python again. I don't know what caused the problem but it's now fixed.

Comment: You got the error because there must have been another file named `tkinter.py` apart from the main module file.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!